# How to take advantage of subprocess within Django? - Django

Tags: python, django, command-line, popen

I'm currently using os.popen() but have been recommended to use **subprocess.popen()** instead.

**Any ideas on how I can integrate this?**

It would be cool and fun to have a **Python shell accessible on a Django app**. But I reckon that it might be a bit complex to implement.

I guess I would have to retrieve the subprocess, as a new request comes in.

---

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

http://www.datamech.com/devan/trypython/trypythonx.py

and then ask him for the source. That's the route I'd go and then just restrict access to the page within Django's auth system.